# Ruby on rails MVC

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день!
Никак не могу реализовать добавление задачи с возможностью выбора раздела для этой задачи.
Есть 2 модели:

Раздел для задачи:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 1 }
end
```

и сама задача с меткой о выполнении:

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

есть контроллер:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @todo = @project.todos.create(todo_params)
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
end

private
def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:text)
end

end
```

Вот форма добавления задачи:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.todos.build]) do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :'Текст задачи' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <%= f.label :'Метка о выполнении' %><br>
    <%= check_box_tag(:isCompleted)%>
  </p> 

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <%= link_to 'submit', "", :onclick => "$('form').submit()" %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Пытаюсь сделать что-то типо этого:

```
      <h2>Добавить задачу:</h2>
<%= select_tag(:project, options_for_select([['Семья', 1], ['Работа', 2], ['Прочее', 3]])) %>
<%= render 'todos/form' %>
```

Но не знаю как связать и передать в render id моего раздела, что бы в него добавить нужную задачу

Вот скрин формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать, нужно сделать очень срочно

Вот мой routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :projects do
    resources :todos
    end
    root 'projects#index'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ох, с чего бы начать...

- Элемент ввода `project_id` должен быть **внутри формы**, поскольку иначе он просто не уйдёт на сервер в её параметрах.

  - Проще всего его `select` просто перенести внутрь формы (вот только это сходу не сработает, ниже расскажу почему).
  - ...но можно добавить в форму только `hidden`-поле, значение в которое записывать JS'ом на основе каких бы там ни было манипуляций с другими вещами на странице.
- Вы почему-то решили держать `project_id` **в корне** параметров (`params[:project_id]`), а не в параметрах объекта, который создаёте (`params[:todo][:project_id]`).

  - ...видимо, потому что этот параметр вы держите в URL, он вшивается в значение атрибута `action` тега `form` и никакими `input`'ами напрямую меняться не может, поскольку с точки зрения HTML **параметром не является**.

    - От `form_for([@project, @project.todos.build])` придётся избавляться, если вы хотите отдельный `input` для `project_id`. В пользу `form_for @todo` или чего бы там ни было ещё.
    - Скорее всего, для этого придётся и роуты изменить, сделав `todos#create` вне блока `resources :projects`. Вложенность ресурсов для вашего случая оказалась скорее вредна, чем полезна. Вы можете разделить маршруты на чтение и запись: чтение сделать красивым и вложенным, а запись практичной и плоской.
  - Если вы после выноса `project_id` в отдельный `input` решили оставить его на том же месте (и не менять код контроллера), то... Вы добрались до `select_tag`, вам не хватает [метода `options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select), который может на основе коллекции моделей и двух методов (под обозначение и значение) подготовить набор `<option>`-элементов, примерно так:

    ```
    select_tag(:project_id,
                options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, :id, :title))
    ```
  - ...а можно разместить `project_id` на месте `params[:todo][:project_id]` (соответственно изменив `todo_params` и процедуру создания, убрав явный поиск `@project`), это позволило бы воспользоваться [`collection_select`'ом](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select) построителя формы:

    ```
    f.collection_select(:project_id, Project.all, :id, :title)
    ```

    Это уже почти красиво.
- `:onclick => "$('form').submit()"` это восхитительный способ прострелить себе ногу в момент, когда на странице станет больше одной формы. Да и кнопка сама по себе делает почти то же самое и без этого атрибута, только ещё форму для отправки при этом выбирает правильнее.

Comment: Извините меня пожалуйста за мою тупость. Программирую в ROR - 3 день (необходимо выполнить тестовое задание). Но я практически ничего не понял из написанного вами. Можно, мне глупому это как то более ясно объяснить, в силу начала моего изучения ROR

Comment: @Alex69rus если вы недостаточно подготовлены для выполнения тестового задания, вы должны его провалить. Так и задумано. Так и работодатель не получит небоеспособного сотрудника, и вы не получите непосильную работу.

Comment: в добавок ко всему, так же нужно реализовать возможность отправки формы через link a не через button

Comment: @Alex69rus да хоть по ховеру на абзац. Сейчас вы повесили код в клик по кнопке (хотя кнопка сама по себе делает почти то же самое, даже лучше), можете повесить в другое интересующее вас событие.

Comment: если не трудно, подскажите каким образом нужно изменить мои роуты и как должна выглядеть моя форма добавления todo в конечном итоге. Что то я тяжело понимаю этот момент

Comment: @Alex69rus я описал, какие черты должны быть у результата. Как его достичь, дело уже ваше. Роут создания `todo` не должен содержать каких бы там ни было параметров (вроде `id` проекта), `rake routes` (не знаю, его заменили в 5.0 на `rails routes`?) должен показать результаты. Пример того, что сделать с формой, я тоже привёл. Ориентируйтесь по тому, какой получается разметка, смотрите в сам HTML.